# Risks of serializing and deserializing json in different newtonsoft versions

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to upgrade my newtonsoft dll,but I have serialized records in my db,is there any risk of upgrade newtonsoft version.Can I correctly deserialized my old records in new versions.In my tests I have no problems.But is there any knowing issue about that?By the way my newtonsoft is too old version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say the risk is pretty low of something breaking due to upgrading Json.Net, but it really depends on what features you are using.  You can only know by running your own extensive tests (sounds like you have already done that) and by reading the [release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases) carefully to find out what changes have been made to Json.Net between the version you were originally using and the version you are using now.